# How to automatically mark the checkbox field as enabled during the onclick event of a cell

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table with many cells and I would like to set a checkbox field as enabled with style="display: none" when somebody tries to click on a particular cell. I should reset this when the user clicks on the same cell again. How should I do this using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes the checkbox is inside the <td> that has been clicked:

```
$('td').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){ 
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').toggle();
    });
});
```

If there's only one global checkbox for all cells, you can just reference it directly instead of doing the find():

```
$('#checkbox-id').toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table td').click(function(){
    $(this).children('input:checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked').toggle('slow');
});​
```

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/p9rRY/

Answer (score 1):

you can use this script to show/hide check box in particular column.

$('table tr td:eq(1)').toggle(function(){ $(this).children(':checkbox').css('display','block');},
function(){ $(this).children(':checkbox').css('display','none');});

Please give specific column index in "eq(index)" where you wanna click to show/hide checkbox. for example in above script column is "1". column index start from 0